# Combining ggplot2 and d3 (gridSVG tutorial results in non-interactive image)

Tags: r, d3.js, svg, ggplot2, interactive

I am following along a simple tutorial about integrating ggplot2 and d3. I am specifically working on Method 2 on this tutorial site (http://timelyportfolio.github.io/gridSVG_intro/). I am trying to replicate the interactive plot (it is the last plot on that page).

I used their same syntax, and inserted it into a .R file, as follows:

```
library(gridSVG)
library(ggplot2)
library(XML)
library(rjson)

set.seed(955)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10), xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3), yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

g4 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(shape=19, aes(color = cond), size=5)
g4
g4.svg <- grid.export("plot1.svg",addClasses=TRUE)

cat(saveXML(g4.svg$svg))

cat(
  '<script> ourdata=',
  rjson::toJSON(apply(g4$data,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x)return(list(x)))),
  '</script>'
)

cat(
  '<script> dataToBind = ',
  'd3.entries(ourdata.map(function(d,i) {return d[0]}))',
  '</script>'
)

cat(
  '<script>\n',
  'scatterPoints = d3.select(".points").selectAll("use");\n',
  'scatterPoints.data(dataToBind)',
  '</script>\n'
)

cat('<script>\n',
    'scatterPoints  
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    //Create the tooltip label
    var tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("g");
    tooltip
    .attr("id","tooltip")
    .attr("transform","translate("+(d3.select(this).attr("x")+10)+","+d3.select(this).attr("y")+")")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("stroke-opacity",.5)
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("fill-opacity",.5)
    .attr("height",30)
    .attr("width",50)
    .attr("rx",5)
    .attr("x",2)
    .attr("y",5);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-22)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("x:" + Math.round(d.value.xvar*100)/100);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-10)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")      
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("y:" + Math.round(d.value.yvar*100)/100);
    })              
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    d3.select("#tooltip").remove();  
    });',
'</script>'
)
```

The only output I get from this script is the plot1.svg file. However, when I open this in a browser (tried Safari and Google Chrome), it is a stagnant version of the image.

I would e-mail the author him/herself. But that contact information is not available. It is meant to be a simple tutorial, and so I am hoping it is a simple solution!

I am pretty new to this interactive component. However, I followed the instructions step-by-step, and was unsure what I may have neglected. Any support or information relevant to solving this problem would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's your resulting document look like?  Is it `<svg> all the plot stuff </svg> <script> all that javascript </script>`?

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the reply! The only output I am getting is the plot1.svg file. If I open it in Rstudio, I see that its general format is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <svg> ggplot and gridsvg stuff and other text I am unfamiliar with </svg>. Upon search, I don't see any <script> </script>.

Comment: any particularly reason you choose d3? there are another interesting options, e.g. like http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_plotly.html

Comment: @Mlavoie Thanks for the comments and good question (sorry for my delay!) What I am actually trying to do is create an interactive plot that is something between a scatterplot and network: It has edges between nodes (network), but each node has a specific x,y position (scatterplot). I actually tried htmlwidgets first! But it seems that htmlwidgets does not allow for multiple geoms (http://hrbrmstr.github.io/metricsgraphics/). So, I got stuck with adding edges to the beautiful scatterplot they show (http://hrbrmstr.github.io/metricsgraphics/). Thank you.

Comment: @MLavoie And yes, their scatterplots are very attractive! I would probably stick with htmlwidgets because of that. So, it is a shame it does not seem you can add lines between points of interest in their scatterplot (http://hrbrmstr.github.io/metricsgraphics/).

Comment: glad to see that you found my post.  Sorry it has taken me so long to find it.  Sounds like you found an answer.  There are also lots of helpful new tools that make this much easier.

For future reference, if you see something like username.github.io/repo, you can find all the source by translating this to http://github.com/username/repo and then file issue or find contact information.  In this case http://github.com/timelyportfolio/gridSVG_intro.

I should also add that this particular post was created with `slidify`.  Now I use `rmarkdown`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDITS**

So, I ended up installing R to see where my original answer went wrong.  I was close.  I missed a `saveXML` call and as @arvi1000 pointed out I didn't source `d3`.  Here's a complete fixed up example.  I just ran it with R 3.2.3 and it'll produce a `myAwesomePlot.html` in your working directory:

```
library(gridSVG)
library(ggplot2)
library(XML)
library(rjson)

set.seed(955)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10), xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3), yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

g4 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(shape=19, aes(color = cond), size=5)

# what does this line do?  It writes the SVG to the file "plot1.svg"?
g4.svg <- grid.export("", addClasses=TRUE)

# create a valid html file
cat("<html><head><script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script></head><body>", file="myAwesomePlot.html")

# I'm assuming this gets the svg content and can write it to a file
cat(saveXML(g4.svg$svg), file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE)

cat(
'<script> ourdata=',
rjson::toJSON(apply(g4$data,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x)return(list(x)))),
'</script>', file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE
)

cat(
  '<script> dataToBind = ',
  'd3.entries(ourdata.map(function(d,i) {return d[0]}))',
  '</script>'
  , file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE)

cat(
  '<script>\n',
  'scatterPoints = d3.select(".points").selectAll("use");\n',
  'scatterPoints.data(dataToBind)',
  '</script>\n'
  , file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE)

cat('<script>\n',
    'scatterPoints  
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    //Create the tooltip label
    var tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("g");
    tooltip
    .attr("id","tooltip")
    .attr("transform","translate("+(d3.select(this).attr("x")+10)+","+d3.select(this).attr("y")+")")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("stroke-opacity",.5)
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("fill-opacity",.5)
    .attr("height",30)
    .attr("width",50)
    .attr("rx",5)
    .attr("x",2)
    .attr("y",5);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-22)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("x:" + Math.round(d.value.xvar*100)/100);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-10)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")      
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("y:" + Math.round(d.value.yvar*100)/100);
    })              
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    d3.select("#tooltip").remove();  
    });',
'</script>'
, file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE)

# close out file
cat("</body></html>", file="myAwesomePlot.html", append=TRUE)
```

---

**Original Answer**

It's been a while since I've done any `R` programming but those `cat` functions  don't look right.  They would be writing to standard out, not into the file.  My guess would be that `grid.export` only writes the `svg` file and everything else is dropped. From a glance I assume you are meant to run this code as:

```
R myRCode.R > outPutFile.svg
```

So that the stdout redirects into a file.

I'd try to restructure the code a bit and write everything into an `html` file explicitly:

```
library(gridSVG)
library(ggplot2)
library(XML)
library(rjson)

set.seed(955)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10), xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3), yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

g4 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(shape=19, aes(color = cond), size=5)
g4

// what does this line do?  It writes the SVG to the file "plot1.svg"?
g4.svg <- grid.export("plot1.svg",addClasses=TRUE)

// create a valid html file
cat("<html><head></head><body>", file="myAwesomePlot.html")

// I'm assuming this gets the svg content and can write it to a file
cat(g4.svg$svg, file="myAwesomePlot.html")

cat(
  '<script> ourdata=',
  rjson::toJSON(apply(g4$data,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x)return(list(x)))),
  '</script>', file="myAwesomePlot.html"
)

// etc, rest of JavaScript

// close out file
cat("</body></html>", file="myAwesomePlot.html")
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did try to restructure this, but it seems that the line cat(g4.svg$svg, file="myAwesomePlot.html") results in an error: "Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : argument 1 (type 'externalptr') cannot be handled by 'cat'" I tried to replace this idea using write(), dput(), among others, but I am unable to write this to the html file.

Comment: This is a good answer, but without a link to the d3.js library, I don't think the result works!

Comment: @LanneR, see updated answer, my apologies I didn't reply sooner.  Thanks for giving me an excuse to fire up `R` again, it's been years since I've used it.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

- You are missing a link to the D3.js library!
- `cat`, as you have it, in a plain R script, just outputs to the console, as @Mark said.

To solve 1) your final html document must contain: `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` or equivalent.

To solve 2), you can work with an Rmarkdown .Rmd file and put everything you have in a chunk.

In a file with an .Rmd extension, begin the chunk with this line:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

next, make sure you include the D3 library with this line:

```
cat('<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>')
```

then add all your code above, and then to end the chunk:

````
```
````

If you are doing this inside Rstudio, you can then hit 'Knit HTML'. Otherwise, you can use `knitr::knit2html` or `rmarkdown::render` from the console or in another .R script)

Comment: Thank you for this support, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like @arvi1000's suggestion to use `knitr` (which is a good one), you can use `sink(file = "myfile.html")` before your first `cat()` statement to write all the output to `myfile.html`. At the end, simply add the statement `sink()` to start writing back to standard output.

Like @arvi1000 said, you are also missing the link to the D3.js library. Following their directions, put `cat('<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>')` as your first `cat()` statement. You may also need to follow @Mark's advice on creating a valid HTML file.

Honestly though, the easiest way is to use `knitr`. I have included the contents of a valid .Rmd file which will produce D3.js plot. Just run `knitr::knit2html()` on a .Rmd file containing the following code. I added some comments with my best interpretation of what is going on (I have never done ggplot to D3.js, so this was a cool learning experience for me!)

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.keep = 'none'}
library(gridSVG)
library(ggplot2)
library(XML)
library(rjson)

# create a plot with some fake data

set.seed(955)
dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10), xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3), yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))

g4 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(shape=19, aes(color = cond), size=5)

# you need to print the plot in order to capture it with grid.export
g4
# exporting the plot to a .svg file
g4.svg <- grid.export("plot1.svg",addClasses=TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

# load the d3.js script
cat('<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>')

# convert the svg file to an XML string and print it 
cat(saveXML(g4.svg$svg))

# looks like you convert the ggplot object data to JSON for use by d3.js
# looks like the aesthetics are included here? I don't seem them defined 
# anywhere else
cat(
  '<script> ourdata=',
  rjson::toJSON(apply(g4$data,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x)return(list(x)))),
  '</script>'
)

# d3.js data definition
cat(
  '<script> dataToBind = ',
  'd3.entries(ourdata.map(function(d,i) {return d[0]}))',
  '</script>'
)

# d3.js scatter plot
cat(
  '<script>\n',
  'scatterPoints = d3.select(".points").selectAll("use");\n',
  'scatterPoints.data(dataToBind)',
  '</script>\n'
)

# d3.js code to support the hover tooltips (hover over a point on the plot)
# this is apparently ALL for the tooltip
cat('<script>\n',
    'scatterPoints  
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    //Create the tooltip label
    var tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("g");
    tooltip
    .attr("id","tooltip")
    .attr("transform","translate("+(d3.select(this).attr("x")+10)+","+d3.select(this).attr("y")+")")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("stroke-opacity",.5)
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("fill-opacity",.5)
    .attr("height",30)
    .attr("width",50)
    .attr("rx",5)
    .attr("x",2)
    .attr("y",5);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-22)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("x:" + Math.round(d.value.xvar*100)/100);
    tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",-10)
    .attr("text-anchor","start")
    .attr("stroke","gray")
    .attr("fill","gray")      
    .attr("fill-opacity",1)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .text("y:" + Math.round(d.value.yvar*100)/100);
    })              
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    d3.select("#tooltip").remove();  
    });',
'</script>'
)
```
````

Comment: Thank you @mikeck! This was very, very helpful!